# Calculating the Harmonic Mean and Geometric Mean Recursively

Tags: recursion

Does anyone have a good example on how to calculate the Harmonic Mean and Geometric Mean Recursively.  Is it possible to use a Tail Recursive function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'recursive' definitions:

```
G(x1,x2,...,xn) = (x1 * G(x2,...,xn)^(n-1))^(1/n)
H(x1,x2,...,xn) = n / ( 1/x1 + (n-1)/H(x2,...,xn) )
```

This isn't efficient way to calculate means, since exponentiation/multiplication is done n times.

Simple python implementation with lists as input parameter (N):

```
def G(N):
  if len(N) == 1: return N[0]
  return (N[0] * G(N[1:])**(len(N)-1))**(1/len(N))

def H(N):
  if len(N) == 1: return N[0]
  return len(N) / ( 1/N[0] + (len(N)-1)/H(N[1:]) )
```

Comment: I think its also possible to calculate a partial harmonic mean.  There should be a way to add the results up independently and then sum them at the end.  Is there another way rather then logarithms that can simplify division or multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

for the geometric mean, I could not use @Ante's method because, in my case, 1) the product would become too small for a float and 2) I couldn't read the full serie at all once but I am discovering values one by one. Therefore I couldn't find a better solution than using the logarithm:

```
int iCount(0);
float GMeanLog(0);
for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
if (iCount > 0)
{
    iGMeanLog = GMeanLog+(log(val[i])-GMeanLog)/iCount;
    iCount++;
}
else
{
    iCount++;
    GMeanLog = log(val[i]);
}
}
```